# Regular expression - Remove special characters except single white space

Tags: regex, oracle

From stack overflow, I got the standard reg expression

```
to eliminate -
a) special characters
b) digits
c) more than 2 spaces to single space
to include -
d) - (hyphen)
e) ' (single quote) 

SELECT ID, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(forenames, '[^A-Za-z-]', ' '),'\s{2,}',' ') ,  REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(surname, '[^A-Za-z-]', ' '),'\s{2,}',' ') , forenames, surname from table1;
```

1. Instead of 2 functions how to get the result in single function?
2. to include '(single quote) \' is not working in regexp_replace.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to double `'` to use a literal `'`. So, you need to shrink `REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(surname, '[^A-Za-z''-]', ' '),'\s{2,}',' '))` into a single `REGEXP_REPLACE`? Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(surname, '([^A-Za-z[:space:]''-]|\s{2,})+', ' ')`

Comment: Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, value ) AS
  SELECT 1, '123a45b£$-   ''c45d@{e''' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '[^a-zA-Z'' -]| +( )',
         '\1'
       )
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | REGEXP_REPLACE(VALUE,'[^A-ZA-Z''-]|+()','\1')
> -: | :--------------------------------------------
>  1 | ab- 'cde'
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4c8548936ba476a3d79bfa8d15162c9c)*